# Tkinter checkbutton updates when checked, but doesn't update when I uncheck it

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm really new to Python, and I am currently working on a random generator, and I intend to use checkbuttons so the user can select what lists they want to generate from. I have mostly everything working, it generates a "Select option" text when the button is clicked and none of the checkbuttons are checked. And it adds the selected lists when the checkbuttons are checked and generates from those with no problem.

My issue comes when I try to uncheck the buttons in the GUI. Once I check them, regardless if they're unchecked or not after, it still generates from the list. I think it has to do with how I'm adding the lists, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
mList = []


root = tk.Tk()


var = tk.IntVar()
var1 = tk.IntVar()

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(height = 5, width = 5, text = "Opt. 1", variable = var)
c1.pack()

c2 = tk.Checkbutton(height = 5, width = 5, text = "Opt. 2", variable = var1)
c2.pack()


generate = tk.StringVar()
generate.set("Your letter will appear here.")


def pressed():
    global mList
    if var.get() == 1:
        mList = (list1)
    if var1.get() == 1:
        mList = (list2) 
    try:
        generate.set(random.choice(mList))
    except IndexError:
        generate.set("Please select an option")


button1 = tk.Button(height = 20, width = 20, text = "Press Me", command = lambda: pressed())
button1.pack()

label = tk.Label(height = 200, width = 200, textvariable = generate)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Is there some way that when the checkboxes are unchecked they remove list1 and list2?

I know that Classes are a thing that make GUI programming easier, as that's pretty much the most common answer on any questions similar to this one, but I'm still trying to learn that.

Comment: What is the expected result when both checkbuttons are checked?

Comment: You can use `if not var.get() and not var1.get(): generate.set("Please select an option")`. Then you can get rid of the `try` clause.

Comment: The expected result for both clicked would be to randomly pick from either list 1 or list 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign `mList` to an empty list.
The whole logic should depend on what you are expecting:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random


list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
mList = []

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar()
var1 = tk.IntVar()

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(height=5, width=5, text="Opt. 1", variable=var)
c1.pack()

c2 = tk.Checkbutton(height=5, width=5, text="Opt. 2", variable=var1)
c2.pack()

generate = tk.StringVar()
generate.set("Your letter will appear here.")


def pressed():
    global mList
    if var.get() == 1:
        mList = list1
    elif var1.get() == 1:
        mList = list2
    else:  # when both var.get() and var1.get() are not 1
        mList = []
    try:
        generate.set(random.choice(mList))
    except IndexError:
        generate.set("Please select an option")


button1 = tk.Button(height=20, width=20, text="Press Me", command=pressed)
button1.pack()

label = tk.Label(height=200, width=200, textvariable=generate)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear `mList` first, then append the required list to it depends on the values of `var` and `var1`.  Also replace `try/except` by `if/else` as below:

```
def pressed():
    mList.clear()
    if var.get() == 1:
        mList.extend(list1)
    if var1.get() == 1:
        mList.extend(list2)
    if mList:
        generate.set(random.choice(mList))
    else:
        generate.set("Please select an option")
```